# Install less compiler with gemfile/bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Just as the title suggests, is it possible to install the less compiler using a gemfile and bundler

Answer (score 1):

The less compiler is installable in ruby through the `less` gem.

To install it through bundler you just need to add the following to your gemfile:

```
gem 'less'
```

then you can install it by running:

```
bundle install
```

Note that the less compiler is a node.js program so it will need a javascript runtime for you to run it. If you try running `lessc` and don't have a javascript runtime installed it will throw an error that explains this. In that case you also want to install something like `therubyracer` gem. Which means you would also want to add:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

to your gemfile.